# spearman correlation: should only the ranked values be plotted on a scatterplot?

Tags: spss, spearman-rho, scatterplot

My data is not normally distributed and so I did a spearman correlation rank test. I now need to make a scatterplot showing the spearman rank test results and I am not sure if the scatterplot should show the ranked values or the raw data values.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What does the normal distribution have to do with the correlation?

Comment: For my dissertation if our results aren't normally distributed instead of using the Pearson correlation test we use the spearman correlation test. Just slightly confused what values are best to show on a scatterplot for the spearman rank test (I.e. ranked values or not ranked values) as for the Pearson correlation we just use our normal data from our analysis.

Comment: Why do you use Spearman if the distributions aren’t normal? And why not give plots of both the raw data and the rank-transformed data?